# Get different test and training sets from the same sample

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have some data for which I want to compare a few different linear models. I can use `caTools::sample.split()` to get one training/test set.

I would like to see how the model would change if I had used a different training/test set from the same sample. If I do not use `set.seed()` I should get a different set every time I call `sample.split`.

I am using `lapply` to call the function a certain number of times right now:

```
library(data.table)
library(caTools)
dat <- as.data.table(iris)
dat_list <- lapply(1:20, function(z) {
  sample_indices <- sample.split(dat$Sepal.Length, SplitRatio = 3/4)
  inter <- dat
  inter$typ <- "test"
  inter$typ[sample_indices] <- "train"
  inter$set_no <- z
  return(as.data.table(inter))})
```

And for comparing the coefficients:

```
coefs <- sapply(1:20, function(z){
  m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = dat_list[[z]][typ == "train"])
  return(unname(m$coefficients))
})
```

The last few lines could be edited to return the RMS error when predicting values in the test set (`typ=="test"`).

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: A better way of doing what? Splitting the data multiple times? Comparing coefficients? Approaching the problem? I'd say you're fine, and if you're happy with the result, move along! You might be interested in k-fold cross-validation instead - it's more common and shares a similar goal. You could do it fairly automatically using `caret`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in splitting the data efficiently (my actual data set is quite large). I am also keen to know if there's a standard way for comparing models in this fashion - I'll look up k-fold method that you mentioned. My knowledge of statistics is poor, sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm interested in splitting the data efficiently (my actual data set is quite large)

I'm a big advocate of lists of data frames, but it doesn't make sense to duplicate your data in a list - especially if it's biggish data, you don't need 20 copies of your data to have 20 train-test splits.

Instead, just store the indices of the train and test sets, and give the appropriate subset to the model.

```
n = 5
train_ind = replicate(n = n, sample(nrow(iris), size = 0.75 * nrow(iris)), simplify = FALSE)
test_ind = lapply(train_ind, function(x) setdiff(1:nrow(iris), x))

# then modify your loop to subset the right rows
coefs <- sapply(seq_len(n), function(z) {
  m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris[train_ind[[z]], ])
  return(m$coefficients)
})
```

It's also good to parameterize anything that is used more than once. If you want to change to 20 replicates, set up your code so you change `n = 20` at the top and don't have to go through the whole thing looking for every time you used `5` to change it to `20`. It might be nice to pull out the `split_ratio = 0.75` and put it on it's own line at the top too, even though it's only used once.

Comment: Good idea, I'll save the indices instead! Now it's just about comparing the models.